# Why are FAT partitions not automounted?

Tags: root, automount, boot-partition

I see this happen in Ubuntu 12.04. When I plug an SD card which contains `boot` and `rootfs` partitions, only the `rootfs` gets automounted but not the boot. The only difference between these two is that `boot` partition is FAT32 type while `rootfs` is ext4 type.

So I understand that Ubuntu does not automount FAT32. But why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The philosophy of Linux is do no harm. So auto mounting anything without your knowledge is no a good idea. If it ain't mounted, its safe. If it did auto mount I would ask the opposite question.

Safety first!

Also NTFS partitions don't ALWAYS auto mount either, probably for the same reason.

Comment: Then why are ext4 partitions automounted? Aren't they harm to linux?

Comment: They are journaled and linux. NTFS and FAT32 are Microsoft. When you write the file system you can vouch for its veracity. When its a third party you can't